# Unzip a file from SDcard

Tags: java, android

I am trying to unzip a file from sdcard using below code

```
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory, String filename) throws IOException {

    File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
           // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();              

                 if (!entry.isDirectory()) {                        
                        // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                        extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
                    } else {
                        // if the entry is a directory, make the directory                      ;
                        File dir = new File(filename);
                        dir.mkdir();
                    }
                    zipIn.closeEntry();
                    entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
                }
                zipIn.close();
            }
            /**
             * Extracts a zip entry (file entry)
             * @param zipIn
             * @param filePath
             * @throws IOException
             */
            private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                }
                bos.close();
            }
```

The above code is giving me errors. below are the logs

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/unZipedFiles/myfile/tt/images.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Here I ziped directory which contains images/sub-directory, then I am trying to unzip.

Can anybody tell me the reasons

Thanks

Comment: Did you create the `/mnt/sdcard/unZipedFiles/myfile/tt/` directory?

Comment: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : have a look on your file exists or not

Comment: Did you mention in your manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @CommonsWare : I have created /mnt/sdcard/unZipedFiles in my SDcard. here myfile is a zipfile I want to unzip that file

Comment: "I have created /mnt/sdcard/unZipedFiles in my SDcard" -- that is good. However, that is not what I asked. Did you create the `/mnt/sdcard/unZipedFiles/myfile/tt/` directory? You are trying to write a file to this directory. If this directory does not exist, you need to create it before you can write a file to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare : How to create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write files to a directory that does not exist. This will not work. Not only do you need to create the *files* when unZIPping, you need to create the *directories* as well.

Add the following to `extractPath()` as its opening line:

```
filePath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

This gets the directory that should contain your desired file (`filePath.getParentFile()`), then creates all necessary subdirectories to get there (`mkdirs()`).